# Advanced settings missing from Tissue Tessellate panel

Tags: add-on, error

I am following a tutorial to learn how to create surface patterns using the Tissue add-on. However, the panel looks completely different than in the tutorial?

In the tutorial there is an additional "Advanced" panel of settings below the standard inputs that is simply not present in mine. It just says "More settings in the Object Data Properties panel..." however there are no additional settings in the properties panel.

I am certain this is just user error but can anyone point me to the right direction with how to use the advanced settings on the tool?

My settings:

[image: My settings]

Tutorial Settings:
[image: Tutorial Settings]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Select the Object Data tab (click the green triangle) on the Properties window and the Tissue Tessellate settings should be on that panel. You may have to open the section with the down arrow as shown below:
[image]